# Processing each file in directory, output with different extension

Tags: python

I have written a Python program that reads a test input file and outputs an output file

```
inputFile = open ('test.dat', 'r')
outputFile = open('test.log', 'w')
outputFile.write(inputFile.read())
inputFile.close()
outputFile.close()
```

I'd like to read all the .dat files in a folder and output corresponding .log files, keeping the file name prefix the same.  Could somebody help me?

I've figured out that I could list all the dat files with the following code.  But don't know what to do from then.

```
import os
for file in os.listdir("."):
    if file.endswith(".htm"):
        print(os.path.join("xxx", file))
```

Also: is there any way to know the count of .dat files in a directory?  This way, while processing each file, I could display the progress status, like: "Processing File 1 of 999 data files", etc.

Thanks a bunch
Joanna

Comment: In one example you copy .dat files to .txt, but in the other you seem to be copying html files to a subdirectory xxx. Which is it?

Comment: @tdelaney I think `.htm` is a sample of how she'll do it.

@JoannaTrussel
Do you want to just copy whatever is in the `.dat` files to `.log` files or are you trying to run the `.dat` files and output a `.log` file?

Comment: @WanmiSiangshai - the point behind the comment is that the poster should tell us. I wrote an answer based on the first example, but its not really an answer until OP clears up the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `glob` to list only the files you want and `shutil.copyfile` to copy them to the new file name. Use the size of the list you get from glob to print progress along the way.

```
from glob import glob
import shutil

dat_files = list(glob("*.dat"))
dat_file_len = len(dat_files)
for i, dat_file in enumerate(dat_files, 1):
    print(f"copying {i} of {dat_file_len}")
    shutil.copyfile(dat_file, datfile[:-4] + ".log")
```

Answer (score 0):

First you would have to get a list of all the `.dat` files contained in the directory, the code would look like this:

```py
import glob
import os

dat_files = glob.glob('*.dat')
for i, dat_file in enumerate(dat_files):
    print("Writing %d file..." %(i+1))
    inputFile = open (dat_file, 'r')
    outputFile = open(dat_file[:-3]+"log", 'w') # removing "dat" from end, and inserting new extension "log"
    outputFile.write(inputFile.read())
    inputFile.close()
    outputFile.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use below program:

```
import glob

files_list = glob.glob('*.dat')

count_dat_file=len(files_list)

print("Count of .dat file is : {}\n".format(count_dat_file))

count_var = 1

for item in files_list:
    print("Pocessing file {} of {}".format(count_var, count_dat_file))
    print("Old File Name is  : {}".format(item))
    file_name_list = item.split('.')
    file_name_list[-1] = 'log'
    new_file_name = '.'.join(file_name_list)
    print("New file Name is  : {}".format(new_file_name))
    with open(item,'r') as input_file:
        with open(new_file_name,'w') as output_file:
            output_file.write(input_file.read())
    print("Data written to new file : {}".format(new_file_name))
    count_var+=1
    print("\n")
```